# How to make SQLDataSource insert into view instead of the underlying table?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatasource, .net-datasourcecontrol

We have replaced 20 tables with a consolidated table, that separates each set of data via a "set id" (all the records for table "A" have a set_id of 1, table "B" is 2, etc.).

We then built views on the table, and renamed each so they had the views had the same names as the original 20 tables, with a WHERE to add the set_id.   Net result - inserts/updates/selects of the views still work

We did this so our web page, which uses a sqldatasource with "sql command builder", wouldn't have to change.  We added an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on each view, so that when you insert into the view, it adds the set_id and inserts into the consolidated table.  So far, so good.

It partially works: UPDATEs and DELETEs work, because they know the actual ID for the record.

However INSERTs don't - when the command actually executes, we see "exec sp_executesql insert into consolidatedtable" - rather than hitting the view, the data source control finds the underlying table, then inserts directly into it.  If we try adding fields to the views, they then show up in the data source control, but the web page then shows a configurable field.

Is there a way to change things on the database side to force it to use the view?  My only other option at this point is to replace the views with tables, add an AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE trigger so that the consolidated gets updated, and then a process to make sure they're in sync and there are no issues.

MANY thanks in advance.

Comment: I setup a test case and it works correctly from SQL Management Studio.  So it appears to be the way the web page communicates with the database that resolves the view to the consolidated table.  Would you  describe more about your web page and how it connects to the db?

Comment: @JamesL. Correct - it works if I run a select via SQL.  The problem is that the SQLDataSource appears to work around the views and issues an insert directly into the underlying table.  This is more a .Net/C#/VB question than a SQL Server question.

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the InsertCommand attribute of <asp:SqlDataSource> the way it's specified in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkzs2t3h(v=vs.100).aspx ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelJSwart Changing the web site is a lot more difficult than changing the SQL.  The devs always want to do it in a programmer-friendly way that doesn't require SQL code or SPs or DBA input, which works well for them (but causes more effort on our side, especially in times like this).